# Does External file format in polybase support Row terminator?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, polybase

I am loading a BCPed data which has few rows that contains newline character in data itself. So when I try to import those data it's throwing an error. To Solve this issue I need to specify row terminator in external file format as \r\n. Does polybase allow row terminator? if so how?

Answer (score 1):

> Does polybase allow row terminator?

Row terminator feature of Polybase is not supported currently. There is a  feature request which related to your question on Azure feedback page. The state of this feature is still under review. Link below is for your reference.

[Polybase: allow field/row terminators within string fields](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/10600132-polybase-allow-field-row-terminators-within-strin)

Comment: This is very important feature as we are stuck and may have to go alternative approach. Do you know when can we expect this feature?

Comment: Since the state of this feature is still under review. We can't get the exact time.